# Trigger Glue from Lambda - S3 event trigger - An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the StartJobRun operation: User:

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-glue

I am trying to trigger a Glue Job from Lambda. It's failing with below error:

> An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the StartJobRun operation: User:

JSON:

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the StartJobRun operation: User: arn:aws:sts::XXXX:assumed-role/xxxx-role/xx-Job is not authorized to perform: glue:StartJobRun on resource: arn:aws:glue:us-east-1:XXXX:job/xx-Job because no identity-based policy allows the glue:StartJobRun action",
  "errorType": "AccessDeniedException",
  "requestId": "38feed94-a0c2-4ed1-843f-7e7f7b1abca2",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 12, in lambda_handler\n    runId = glue.start_job_run(JobName=gluejobname)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/client.py\", line 534, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/client.py\", line 976, in _make_api_call\n    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)\n"
  ]
}
```

Lambda code,

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    
    glue = boto3.client('glue')
    gluejobname = "AWS_ETL_Load"
    
    try:
        runId = glue.start_job_run(JobName=gluejobname)
        status = glue.get_job_run(JobName=gluejobname, RunId=runId['JobRunId'])
        print("Job Status : ", status['JobRun']['JobRunState'])
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise
```

Which role am I missing? I am unable to find the role in AWS documentation as well.

Comment: What is the full error message? Seems like you've copied only the first line.

Comment: Updated the complete error message

Answer (score 1):

The error means that your **lambda execution role** `arn:aws:sts::XXXX:assumed-role/xxxx-role/xx-Job` does not have permissions to run `glue:StartJobRun`. So you have to amend your role and add such permissions.

It could also be possibile that you are denied such actions, on other levels then your lambda, e.g. SCP, boundary conditions. Then you have to modify those as well.